# How to calculate marginal density and identify which one they are?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, density-function

Let $f_{UV}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1\lambda_2 e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left((\lambda_1 +\lambda_2)u + (\lambda_2 - \lambda_1)v \right)}$ the joint density of U and V random variables. I have to decide if X and Y are independent, by calculating marginal density. However I'm getting in trouble, because I didn't find that U and V are independent. Would you help me please?

The problem is that I couldn't identify the marginals as any density known.

$X\sim Exp(\lambda_1)$  , $Y\sim Exp(\lambda_2)$, where $U=X+Y$ and $V=X−Y$. I calculated the joint density of $(U,V)$, using Jacobian Method. Now I'm struggling to show if $U$, $V$ are independent.

Comment: I think some information is missing. What is given about $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$? What is the domain $x, y$ where pdf is valid?

Comment: Indeed! $X\sim Exp(\lambda_1)$ , $Y\sim Exp(\lambda_2)$, where $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$. I calculated the joint density of (U,V), using Jacobian Method. Now I'm struggling to show if U, V are independent.

Comment: OK, you should edit your question to include your last comment. Without that, the question seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_X(x) = \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}, f_Y(y) = \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 y}$

$f_{XY} (x, y) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-(\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 y)}$

$U = X + Y, V = X-Y$ and using,

$x = \frac{u+v}{2}, y = \frac{u-v}{2}$ ...(i)

Joint pdf of $U$ and $V$, $f_{UV}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1\lambda_2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \big((\lambda_1 +\lambda_2)u + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)v \big)}$

Now to find marginal pdf of $U$ and $V$,

Please note from $(i)$ that $-u \leq v \leq u$ or $|v| \leq u$

So, $f_U(u) = \displaystyle \int_{-u}^{u} f_{UV}(u, v) \ dv$

$f_V(v) = \displaystyle \int_{|v|}^{\infty} f_{UV}(u, v) \ du$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: In fact, being able to write a joint pdf under the form $f_{X,Y}(u,v)=f_1(u)f_2(v)$ gives at once the independence of $X$ and $Y$ ; moreover $f_1$ and $f_2$ are their resp. marginals pdf.

Comment: @JeanMarie Based on comments from OP, it is the other way round. At least that is my understanding. $X, Y$ are independent. OP found the joint pdf for $U, V$ $(X+Y, X-Y)$ and wants to now find their marginal pdfs of $U, V$ and then establish whether $U, V$ are independent or not. They are in fact not independent.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for misunderstanding...

Comment: @MathLover Thanks very much for your help!